# RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0 Map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider

I am trying to write add to cart logic using provider, so u am doing the post request with the specific url from the API. Also I created the Map instead of List and write this function. Also i am trying to get element of the map. And I got the error: `RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0`

My provider logic for this:

```
class AddToCart with ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<String, ProductToBasket> _productCart = {};

  Map<String, ProductToBasket> get itemsInCart {
    return _productCart;
  }



  void addInCart({ final String? productId}) async {
    if (_productCart.containsKey(productId)) {
      try {
        final res = await http.post(
            Uri.parse('https://secureLink/api/baskets/products'), body: {
              'productId' : productId.toString()
        });
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
        rethrow;
      }
    } else {
      try {
        _productCart.putIfAbsent(productId!, () => ProductToBasket(productId: productId));
        await http.post(
            Uri.parse('https://secureLink/api/baskets/products'), body: {
          'productId' : productId.toString()
        });
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
        rethrow;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

in my ui I call the function inside the onPressed function and here I got error I descrobed above:

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {providerAddToCart.addInCart(productId: providerAddToCart.itemsInCart.values.elementAt(index).productId);},
    icon: FaIcon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart,
      size: 14,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your "**_productCart**" list first. tell me more details about it.

Comment: I am just thinking about to dynamically change the icon whaen I put something in the cart. Also I am usong post request and whaen I am trying to execute it I got this from the api: 
  "error": {
    "message": "",
    "code": 0,
    "request": {
      "quantity": "shouldn't be null",
      "productId": "shouldnt be null"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I was thinking i need to use post-request to put somerthing  in the cart or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, Use the POST method for saving the product details to the cart.